# Conditional expectation clarification.

Tags: probability-theory

I need to show that $\mathbb E[X_{n+1} | \mathbb F_n] \leq X_n$. My question is this: does it suffice to show that $\mathbb E[X_{n+1} * \mathbb{1}_A] \leq \mathbb E[X_n * \mathbb{1}_A]$ for all $A \in \mathbb F_n$, where $\mathbb F_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, \dots, X_n$? If the less than signs were equals signs, I know this would be true, but I'm not sure that this is necessarily true by the definition of conditional expectation when we have inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} 1_A] \le \mathbb{E}[X_n 1_A]$ for $A \in \mathbb{F}_n$ then properties of conditional expectation give
$$\mathbb{E}[(X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_n]) 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[(X_n - X_{n+1}) 1_A] \ge 0.$$
Now apply this with $A = \{X_n \le \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_n]\} \in \mathbb{F}_n$.  Then $(X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_n]) 1_A \le 0$ a.s., but its expectation is nonnegative, so we have $(X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_n]) 1_A = 0$ a.s.  This is only possible if $X_n \ge \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_n]$ a.s.